# Swift setsockopt SOL_SOCKET SO_RCVTIMEO gets invalid argument

Tags: swift, sockets, invalid-argument

The following playground demonstrates the problem.

```
    //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
    import Foundation
    var s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
    var tv = timeval()
    tv.tv_sec = 3
    tv.tv_usec = 100000
    let tvSize = socklen_t(sizeof(timeval))
    setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, tvSize)
    NSError(domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: Int(errno), userInfo: nil)
```

The result is `setsockopt()` gets -1 and NSError returns `EINVAL`

```
    Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=22 "Invalid argument"
```

This is Mac OS X 10.11, xcode Version 7.0 beta 5 (7A176x)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The poster asked the same question in the Apple forums, and an Apple engineer [responded with details](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/43144?et=watches.email.thread#43144).

The gist of the solution is that to interoperate with C APIs you generally need to use `strideof(T)` which takes trailing structure padding into account in the same way as C's `sizeof()` operator.  The more commonly used `sizeofValue()` doesn't do this.

This problem doesn't reveal itself when running on 32-bit models (i.e. up to and including iPhone 5) where `sizeofValue(timeval)` and `strideof(timeval)` are both 8.

On 64-bit models the corresponding sizes are 12 and 16, causing the O/S to complain with `EINVAL` when 12 is passed instead of the expected 16.

Answer (score -1):

This isn't actually a Swift issue. SO_-related options are finicky. OpenGroup.org says:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsockopt.html

> Note that not all implementations allow this option to be set.

In this case Linux & Mac OS X agree though: You can't do this until the socket is in a connected state, e.g. for TCP: `bind`, `listen`, `accept`, and then set that option on the result, not on the unconnected listener.

Other random Internet advice use `select()` instead to handle timing issues.

Comment: It actually _is_ a Swift issue, since `sizeofValue(timeval)` in Swift is not the same as `sizeof(struct timeval)` in C.  The latter counts padding, and the former doesn't.